# How to wrap an Angular component around a dynamic component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an app that needs horizontal scrolling for many different types of lists. It's a music app, so I have horizontal scrolling for album images, featured images, etc. I've generated some html that creates the horizontal scrolling for a list of album items like so:

```
<div class="hs-grid">
  <div class="hs full"">
      <app-album-item *ngFor="let releaseEl of releases" [submission]="releaseEl"></app-album-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which creates something like this:
[image]

My question is, how can I convert the grid html in to a component so that I don't have to duplicate the grid code for each of the different types of horizontally scrolling items. Essentially something like:

```
<app-horizontal-scroll-grid>
    <app-album-item *ngFor="let releaseEl of releases" [submission]="releaseEl"></app-album-item>
    <!-- IT CAN ALSO BE FEATURED ITEMS -->
    <app-featured-item *ngFor="let featuredItem of featured" [featuredItem]="featuredItem"></app-featured-item>
</app-horizontal-scroll-grid>
```

Obviously this wouldn't work...

How should I pass through the list of items to be used inside the `horizontal-grid-component` since it can be a different **type of component** such as:

- `app-album-item`
- `app-featured-item`
- etc?

I know that if I only had one type of component I needed to horizontally scroll, I could place the `app-album-item` inside the `horizontal-scroll-grid` component HTML and pass through the list of items to an `@Input()`, but since the type of component changes, I am a little confused!

Thanks for any help/insight!

Comment: Take 2 inputs. First Input as you said could be for items and the second Input could be of inner component selection and using the second input you can run a switch case on inner components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ng-content` directive allows to insert components and HTML content dynamically inside another component. [This article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/) by Angular University gives more details about content projection in Angular.

You could define the "scroller" component template as:

```
<div class="hs-grid">
  <div class="hs full"">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

And include other components inside of the scroller in the parent component template:

```
<app-horizontal-scroll-grid>
  <app-album-item *ngFor="let releaseEl of releases" ...></app-album-item>
</app-horizontal-scroll-grid>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxsyzc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: Never knew about `ng-content`! Thanks for linking the Angular University link, this does exactly what I need :)